# Planar surface detection

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am curious if it's possible to detect planar surfaces on camera without any preset textures to match on Android? What is the way to do it?
I've found a couple of Image recognitions & Augmented Reality SDK's, like [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/) or [CraftAR](http://catchoom.com/product/craftar/augmented-reality-sdk/), but from what I've read they're based on preloaded textures which they search in realtime on image.